# How to remove duplicate from an Array and sort it?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have array A :

> **Input:**
>
> > A ={2,3,2,{1},3,2,{0},3,2,0,11,7,9,{2}}

I want output to be Array B

> **Output:**
>
> B={0,1,2,3,7,9,11}

How can i remove the duplicate values and sort them ascending with PHP?

Comment: Use `array_unique()`  method

Answer (score 3):

if you have:

```
$a = array(2,3,2,1,3,2,0,3,2,0,11,7,9,2);
```

you can use [**array_unique()**](http://php.net/manual/it/function.array-unique.php) to remove duplicates:

```
$a = array_unique($a);
```

and then use [**asort()**](http://php.net/manual/it/function.asort.php) to sort the array values:

```
asort($a);
```

Comment: asort sorts in place and returns a boolean of success(in practice always true, since a failure is a fatal error). Assigning a to the result of `asort` will always leave you with `true` in `$a` and not the sorted array.

Comment: @scagar: you're right, I fix it :)

Answer (score 2):

//Try this out...

```
$array = array(2,3,2,(1),3,2,(0),3,2,0,11,7,9,(2));
$array_u = array_unique($array);
sort($array_u);
print_r($array_u);
```

Sample output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 7
    [5] => 9
    [6] => 11
)
```

Comment: Op wanted ascending sort so asort() is better ;)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php

By default sort works as asort() :)

Comment: true :) you're right

Answer (score 0):

First step: flattern

```
function flatten(array $array) {
    $return = array();
    array_walk_recursive($array, function($a) use (&$return) { $return[] = $a; });
    return $return;
}
```

then using [`asort`](http://php.net/manual/it/function.asort.php) and [`array_unique`](http://php.net/manual/it/function.array-unique.php) you can remove duplicates and sort ascendent.

```
$result = array_unique(flattern($array));
asort($result);
```

Sources:
[How to Flatten a Multidimensional Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319903/how-to-flatten-a-multidimensional-array)